# Add NumberPicker value to current textview string

Tags: java, android, string, math, textview

im trying to take the value of several numpickers and add them all together to display on a TextView. Im trying to take the textview string and add any changes to my number pickers. Just as

```
  current_number_text= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_number);
  NumberPicker np1 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.npId);
  NumberPicker np2 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.npId2);
  np1.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener()
  {
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, 
                int newVal)
            {
                    current_number_text.setText("" + (newVal * 10)); 
                    current_weight_view.setText("" + (newVal + np1.getValue() + np2.getValue())); 
            }        
        });

  np2.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener()
        {
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, 
                int newVal)
            {
                  current_weight_view.setText("" + (newVal + np1.getValue() + np2.getValue())); 
            }        
        });
```

So basically i just want to add strings from the `newVal`'s in each number pick to then display in the current_number_text TextView.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
np1.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener()
        {
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, 
                int newVal)
            {
                    current_number_text.setText("" + (newVal + np2.getValue())); 
            }        
        });
```

and similar in `np2` changeListener

or you can also use `variables` for storing values and add them...

**EDIT**
is this what u r looking for

```
current_weight_view.setText("" + current_weight_view.getText() + newVal + np2.getValue());
```

Comment: This is very close, now i need to get the value from the multiplication that is done `.setText("" + (newVal * 20));`from there i can add to the textview number picker and add it, currently it only adds the main number values 1,2,3...10.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this link for example :

http://gafurbabu.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/android-number-picker-dialog/
for more reference you can use this link:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html

i hope you will success.